# Rails3: form_tag to access controller array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Study -> has_many Topics -> has_many References

My Model has the following method to access references based on topic ID:

```
  def self.rel_references(topic_id)
    Reference.where(:topic_id => topic_id)
  end
```

I am accessing the above in my controller as follows:

```
@references= Study.rel_references(params[:topic_id])
```

I need to have a form on the Study model's Show page to access the references based on the topics the user clicks. (A remote form that loads references based on the topic_id). The way I am trying to do this is:

```
  - form_tag rel_references, :id=>"references_form", :method => 'get' do               
    = text_field_tag :topic_id, params[:topic_id]
    = submit_tag "Get references"
```

However, I am not being able to access the references in my view. Please help me understand what I may be doing wrong here. I am very new to Rails so I might be missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: just a note here, you didn't show that actual model relationships 'code' however i'm guessing that you don't need rel_references method, instead do: current_study.references.topic to get all the topics. One thing that confuses me is that the rel_references method is a static or class method, and you avoid the Study->Topics relationship all together, why? Maybe explain why "Study.rel_references" and "self.rel_references", might help to understand a little more.

Comment: @AndrewLank the reason why I have to access the references through the rel_references method and not directly as current_study.topics.references is that I only need to retrieve the references for a particular topic and references belong to topic which in turn belongs to Study. Therefore, after accessing all Topics (using study.topics) I want to be able to access references based on the selection of topic_id : hence the method to accept topic_id param. Please let me know if I was able to clarify. Forgive my lack of knowledge about Rails terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the deprecated Style block helper - and replacing it with = in my form solved this problem for me. My form Now looks like:

```
= form_tag rel_references, :id=>"references_form", :method => 'get' do               
  = text_field_tag :topic_id, params[:topic_id]
  = submit_tag "Get references"
```